# Magento 2 - move product box HTML to another template

Tags: php, magento2

I'm trying to move the HTML that renders a product box (everything that's in the `product-item-info` div when products are rendered in a loop on `list.phtml`). This is on Magento 2.4.3-p1.

I need to do this as I want to re-use the same layout in a couple of places in the site - for example, to render a custom selection of products on the homepage and probably re-use the same box for related products when viewing a single product. Currently, I have to maintain the same code in two places.

I assumed I should be able to define a new block such as `product.list.box` by adding an entry into `catalog_category_view.xml` such as:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.list.box" as="product_list_box" template="Magento_Catalog::product/product-box.phtml">
```

I would then reference in my `list.phtml` template such as `echo($block->getBlockHtml('product_list_box'));`.

However, this doesn't render anything, but I think also creates a problem that I need to inject a custom ViewModel, as well as setting the product to render and pass in other dependencies (such as  the `$viewMode`, `$imageDisplayArea` and a bunch of other things the standard Luma theme needs to render a product).

**So**, what's the correct way to move the rendering of a product box into another template? As a relatively new Magento developer, this seems like it should be straightforward, but I can't get the right combination of code to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a new block, don't forget to define it's position. First, use `<referenceBlock>` or `<referenceContainer>` to define the place you want to put your block.

Then in your block, you can make good use of `before` or `after` attributes to define the position of your new block.

You can refer to [Official Document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_xml-instrux_before-after) for more usages and examples.